# Replacing multiple characters in Ruby string with one character

Tags: ruby, string, replace

I'm trying to replace all vowels in a string with a "*"

This is what I have at the moment

```
string = "alphabet"

string.gsub! "a", "*"
string.gsub! "e", "*"
string.gsub! "i", "*"
string.gsub! "o", "*"
string.gsub! "u", "*"
```

I want string to equal "*lph*b*t".
What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Refer to the documentation at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub It provides an answer to exactly what you're asking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest I can think of is:

```
string.tr!("aeiou", "*")
```

Answer (score 5):

The other standard way is:

```
string = "alphabet"
string.gsub!(/[aeiou]/,'*')
  #=> "*lph*b*t" 
string
  #=> "*lph*b*t"
```

which you could also write

```
string.gsub!(/[aeiou]/) {'*'}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript, Below is one of way to do this.

```
const vArr = 'aeiouy'.split('');

  const sArr = inputStr.split('');

  const binaryArray = sArr.map(i => {
    if(vArr.indexOf(i) > -1){
      return "0"; //I am trying to replace all vowels with zero
    } else {
      return i  //else replace with same char
    }
  })

  const resultStr = binaryArray.join('');
```